# Best practices for seeding random and numpy.random in the same program

Tags: python, numpy, random, random-seed

In order to make random simulations we run reproducible later, my colleagues and I often explicitly seed the `random` or `numpy.random` modules' random number generators using the `random.seed` and `np.random.seed` methods. Seeding with an arbitrary constant like 42 is fine if we're just using *one* of those modules in a program, but sometimes, we use both `random` and `np.random` in the same program. I'm unsure whether there are any best practices I should be following about how to seed the two RNGs together.

In particular, I'm worried that there's some sort of trap we could fall into where the two RNGs together behave in a "non-random" way, such as [both generating the exact same sequence of random numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49196798/1709587), or one sequence trailing the other by a few values (e.g. the kth number from `random` is always the k+20th number from `np.random`), or the two sequences being related to each other in some other mathematical way. (I realise that pseudo-random number generators are all imperfect simulations of true randomness, but I want to avoid exacerbating this with poor seed choices.)

With this objective in mind, are there any particular ways we should or shouldn't seed the two RNGs? I've used, or seen colleagues use, a few different tactics, like:

- Using the same arbitrary seed:

  ```
  random.seed(42)
  np.random.seed(42)
  ```
- Using two different arbitrary seeds:

  ```
  random.seed(271828)
  np.random.seed(314159)
  ```
- Using a random number from one RNG to seed the other:

  ```
  random.seed(42)
  np.random.seed(random.randint(0, 2**32))
  ```

... and I've never *noticed* any strange outcomes from any of these approaches... but maybe I've just missed them. Are there any officially blessed approaches to this? And are there any possible traps that I can spot and raise the alarm about in code review?

Answer (score 4):

I will discuss some guidelines on how multiple pseudorandom number generators (PRNGs) should be seeded. I assume you're not using random-behaving numbers for information security purposes (if you are, only a cryptographic generator is appropriate and this advice doesn't apply).

- To reduce the risk of correlated pseudorandom numbers, you can use PRNG algorithms, such as SFC and other so-called "counter-based" PRNGs (Salmon et al., "Parallel Random Numbers: As Easy as 1, 2, 3", 2011), that support independent "streams" of pseudorandom numbers. There are other strategies as well, and I explain more about this in "[Seeding Multiple Processes](https://peteroupc.github.io/random.html#Seeding_Multiple_Processes)".
- If you can use NumPy 1.17, note that that version introduced a new PRNG system and added SFC (`SFC64`) to its repertoire of PRNGs. For NumPy-specific advice on parallel pseudorandom generation, see "[Parallel Random Number Generation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/random/parallel.html)" in the NumPy documentation.
- You should avoid seeding PRNGs (especially several at once) with timestamps.
- You mentioned [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36376888) in a comment, when I started writing this answer. The advice there is not to seed multiple instances of the same kind of PRNG. This advice, however, doesn't apply as much if the seeds are chosen to be unrelated to each other, or if a PRNG with a very big state (such as Mersenne Twister) or a PRNG that gives each seed its own nonoverlapping pseudorandom number sequence (such as SFC) is used. The accepted answer there (at the time of this writing) demonstrates what happens when multiple instances of .NET's `System.Random`, with sequential seeds, are used, but not necessarily what happens with PRNGs of a different design, PRNGs of multiple designs, or PRNGs initialized with unrelated seeds. Moreover, .NET's `System.Random` is a poor choice for a PRNG precisely because it allows only seeds no more than 32 bits long (so the number of pseudorandom sequences it can produce is limited), and also because it has implementation bugs (if I understand correctly) that have been preserved for backward compatibility.